# asp.net-core least steps to create and save new entry from API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to take a few post query parameters from an API i have and create a new entry.  I wanted to do this with in the method with out needing to load context or something.

```
namespace fais.printing_services.Controllers
{

    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class printController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;

        public printController(IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment)
        {
            _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
        }
        /**/
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult request(string id="test_default", string url = "", string html = "")
        {
                print_job _print_job = new print_job();

                _print_job.html = html;
                _print_job.options = options; //json object string
                _print_job.url = url;

                using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    db.print_job.Add(_print_job);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            return Json(new
                {
                    save = true
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to be able create a new print_job entry and save it when the API is called and return a json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ApplicationDbContext` to controller constructor, it will be injected automatically (if your `Startup.cs` is [like recommeneded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)):

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

public printController(IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment, ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
    _db = db;
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult request(string id="test_default", string url = "", string html = "")
{
    var _print_job = new print_job() 
    {
        html = html,
        options = options,
        url = url,
    }

    _db.print_job.Add(_print_job);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { save = true });
}
```

Comment: lol I had just figured that out and came to solve this lol.  100% spot on.  thank you